# Why does the camera's rotation jump at the end of a Three.js animation when using GSAP for camera movement?

Tags: three.js, gsap

This camera animation is working beautifully, except for the snap rotation at the end.

Demo of the problem: https://youtu.be/Djo80EMwfvA

## Research

[Camera Movement In Three.js Using GSAP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2ouLOL6C4c)

Based on this video I thought maybe using timeline() was the issue and I needed something similar, but I tried gsap.to() and got basically the same result.

[Three.js FirstPersonControls camera rotation jumps back after GSAP tween / restart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773526/three-js-firstpersoncontrols-camera-rotation-jumps-back-after-gsap-tween-resta)

This looked promising, but I'm not using FirstPersonControls.

[How to avoid camera jumps during/after Tween/animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772151/how-to-avoid-camera-jumps-during-after-tween-animation)

I'm not using TWEEN or SLERP.

## Code

### Minimal reproducible example

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/liveNathan/pen/rNPMyxV)

### gsap animation

This is where the animation happens

```
timeline.clear();
timeline.fromTo(camera.position,
            {...camera.position},
            {
                ...newPosition, onUpdate: function () {
                    controls.update();
                }
            }
        );
```

### fitCameraToSelection()

That gsap animation happens inside of fitCameraToSelection.

```
/**
 * Adjusts the camera to fit a selection of objects within the view.
 * The camera view can be oriented from top, side or front, and has calculated distance.
 * The distance calculation will depend on the camera's field of view and its aspect ratio.
 * The function offers different calculations based on whether the object is an array, has a specific orientation, or if it is null.
 *
 * @param {Array} objects - The objects that the camera must adapt to. If empty, the function traverses the entire scene to get the outer boundary.
 * @param {number} offset - The offset for the camera from the objects. A larger offset will move the camera further away. Default value is 1.
 * @param {string|null} orientation - The orientation of the camera. Valid values are "TOP", "SIDE", "FRONT" or null. If null, the function will adapt the camera based on the objects and offset.
 */
function fitCameraToSelection(objects = [], offset = 1, orientation = null) {
    if (!userInteracted) {
        const timeline = gsap.timeline({defaults: {duration: 1}});
        const box = new THREE.Box3();

        if (objects.length > 0) {
            objects.forEach(object => {
                box.expandByObject(object.mesh);
            });
        } else {
            scene.traverse(child => {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    box.expandByObject(child);
                }
            });
        }

        const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
        const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

        const maxSize = Math.max(size.x, size.y, size.z);
        const fitHeightDistance = maxSize / (2 * Math.atan((Math.PI * camera.fov) / 360));
        const fitWidthDistance = fitHeightDistance / camera.aspect;
        const distance = offset * Math.max(fitHeightDistance, fitWidthDistance);

        const direction = controls.target.clone().sub(camera.position).normalize().multiplyScalar(distance);

        controls.maxDistance = distance * 2;
        controls.target = center;

        let newPosition;
        if (orientation) {
            switch (orientation) {
                case "TOP":
                    newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(center.x, center.y, center.z + distance);
                    break;
                case "SIDE":
                    newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(center.x, center.y + distance, center.z);
                    break;
                case "FRONT":
                    newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(center.x + distance, center.y, center.z);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            newPosition = controls.target.clone().sub(direction);
        }

        timeline.clear();
        timeline.fromTo(camera.position,
            {...camera.position},
            {
                ...newPosition, onUpdate: function () {
                    controls.update();
                }
            }
        );

        camera.near = distance / 10;
        camera.far = distance * 10;

        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        controls.update();
    }
}
```

Should I include more code or is that enough?
Here's the repo: https://github.com/LiveNathan/sound-system-model

Comment: I put together a minimal reproducible example today and discovered the problem happens as soon as you add this line: `THREE.Object3D.DEFAULT_UP.set(0, 0, 1);`

I tried several possible solution including temporarily disable the orbit controls during the animation. No luck.

Comment: I posted a GitHub issue about this. The reply was that the camera cannot be parallel to lookAt. I have tried several solutions in this regard without success.

Answer (score 2):

I may not quite understand what you want to do. In your example on codepen there is no camera rotation. I haven't modified it much.
If you are using MapControls. As far as I understand, the problem is that when you animate controls.target, before the animation starts, you need to disable

```
controls.enableDamping = false;
controls.enabled = false.
```

But you don't have it. At the end of the rotation animation, the camera will have some kind of rotation angle; after the end of the animation, the camera position is preserved but the angle becomes equal to 0. In my work, I rotate the camera after the animation along the required axis to 0. In the animate function, I disable

```
if( !isRotate ) { 
  controls .update(delta)
}
```

while the camera is rotating.  https://codepen.io/sdfsd43543/pen/oNmEyVJ

If you rotate the camera before the animation, then at the end of the animation you will have a camera jump. I think you need to get the current camera position and rotation at the end of the animation and copy it to the camera.

Comment: Hey алекс вап, thanks for submitting your answer. What I want to do is be able to animate the camera movement without a jump at the end. If you take a look at the YT video in the original post, you'll the issue.

Comment: Here's what I see when I run your Codepen: https://youtu.be/J2tpUComAfY

The Move Camera button does not center the cube on the screen as it did previously. But, it also does not have the jump in animation at the end.

Comment: I have attempted to impelement your suggested changes in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/liveNathan/pen/gOqeByJ

Unfortunately, the snap rotation at the end of the animation remains in effect.

Comment: Hi алекс, do you have any other thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install this.controls.enableDamping = false; this.controls.enabled = false. this.isRotate = true  after moving the camera.  rotate the camera to its original position  this.camera.rotation.z = 0. I use MapControls.

```js
    onClick = () => {
        if(this.selectMesh){
            const position = this.selectMesh.position
            const tl = gsap.timeline();
            this.controls.enableDamping = false; 
            this.controls.enabled = false 
         
            tl
            .to(this.controls.target, {
                x: position.x, 
                y: 0,
                z: position.z,
                duration: 1.5,
                onComplete: () => {
            }},0)
            .to(this.camera.position, {
                x: position.x, 
                y: 1500,
                z: position.z,
                duration: 1.5,
                onComplete: () => {
                    this.isRotate = true
                }
            },0)
            .to(this.camera.rotation, {
                z: 0,
                duration: 1.5,
                onComplete: () => {
                    this.controls.enableDamping = true; 
                    this.controls.enabled = true 
                    this.isRotate = false
                }
            })
        }
    }


render() {
    const delta = this.clock.getDelta();
    if( !this.isRotate ) {
        this.controls.update(delta)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi алекс вап. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this question. I really want to test it out and mark it as the solution, but I can't figure out how to integrate your suggestion into the MRE in the Codepen in the question above. Would you be willing to fork the Codepen and add your solution?